# SXA 1.8 site set up via TDS not serializing properly

Tags: tds

I am working on a site that has been serialized using TDS.  I am finding that in the Experience Editor I see body-top and body-bottom placeholders.  I've found mention of this issue being caused by the Theme not being serialized properly.  Have tried to get the person who created the site and added it to the repo to redo the theme with no more success than the first attempt.

On looking at the tenant, site, and site settings - there are empty fields for things like the template and media library values.  If I look at the TDS items they have valid looking GUIDs as their values, and TDS believes that the Sitecore database has those values - but looking in Sitecore raw values the fields are blank.  If I search in Sitecore on that GUID - there is an item that exists.

I have restored to Sitecore:

```
/templates/Project/<Tenant>
/media library/themes/<tenant>
/media library/project/<tenant>
/forms/<tenant>
/content/<tenant>
```

I figure the fact that there are blank fields that should have a value is causing the issue with Experience Editor not working as expected (ie. showing these additional placeholders) - but am not sure why TDS thinks the field values are synched when I can't see that reflected in Sitecore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a known Sitecore 9.1 bug.

The response from Hedgehog:

> When you try to serialize an item from the Sitecore admin page it will
>   end up in the serialization folder. When you use that same
>   already-serialized item as a re-introduce it to Sitecore using the
>   Update option, it loses the values of these shared fields, TDS uses
>   the same serialization/update logic behind the scenes as Sitecore, so
>   that's why you're not seeing the fields updated.

and for further reference/discussion:
https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/issues/283